# Simplification and patterns

Tags: simplifying-expressions, replacement, pattern-matching

I have a very simple simplification to make, where I need to do a replacement but the pattern matching seems slightly awkward.

I would like to simplify:

```
0.1 Sqrt[10. + 11. c]
```

to give me

```
Sqrt[0.1 + 0.11 c]
```

Simplify on its own doesn't do this, so I wanted to use a replacement rule. The terms inside the square root are not always the same in what I'm trying to do. This does work for this particular example:

```
Replace[0.1 Sqrt[10. + 11. c],Times[a_, Power[Plus[b_, Times[d_, e_]], Rational[1, 2]]] :> Sqrt[a^2 b + a^2 d e]]
```

but this doesn't:

```
Replace[0.1 Sqrt[10. + 11. c], Times[a_, Power[b_, Rational[1, 2]]] :> Sqrt[a^2 b]]
```

In the second example I want b to be anything, including an expression of the form Plus[_]. I have played with Levels, and Heads, but this doesn't seem to work.

Any ideas?

Comment: Use `Sqrt @ Expand[a^2 b]` instead of `Sqr[a^2 b]`.

Comment: As suggested by @CarlWoll, `0.1 Sqrt[10. + 11. c] /. a_ * Power[x_, 1/2] :> Power[Expand[a^2 x], 1/2]`